# .htaccess rules cause 500 Internal error in my second domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have two websites on the same hosting, my root website uses .htaccess and I can browse it successfully, but my second domain sends me 500 Internal server error . if i delete the .htaccess i can browse both sites well, but i need the .htaccess for my first website.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|uploads|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

file structure

```
-js
-css
-second-domain.com ( here lies my second domain, i cant browse it , 500 internal server problem )
-upload
.htaccess
index.php
sitemap.xml
```

I do hope someone gives me the right commands to put in .htaccess to be able to visit my second domain, thanks in advance.

Comment: sometimes we can fix this problem by enabling mod_rewrite module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It rewrites only non-existent directories/files to index.php. Therefore, you won't have any problem anymore with your existing directories/files